# siguiente iteración del forEach al recibir una respuesta en el subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

intento ejecutar este forEach y que pase a la siguiente iteración solo cuando se reciba una respuesta en el observable, vi que se puede usar forkjoin, pero no me quedo nada claro su uso

```
this.selection.selected.forEach((item) => {
            this.dialogService
              .open(WindowDeleteConfirmComponent, context)
              .onClose.subscribe((val) => {
                console.log("respuesta, siguiente iteracion");
              })
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

Se podría hacer de forma recursiva en lugar del `forEach`:

```js
procesar(items, index){
  // caso base, si el indice es igual a la longitud
  // retornar
  if(index == items.length) return;
  // ejecutar código asíncrono
  
  let item = items[index];
  
  this.dialogService
     .open(WindowDeleteConfirmComponent, context)
     .onClose.subscribe((val) => {
            // cuando se emita un valor llamar de nuevo 
            // a la función procesar en el siguiente elemento
             this.procesar(items, index++);
      })
}
// llamada inicial
this.procesar(this.selection.selected, 0);
```